# Loop within a loop in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, date, loops

I'm having a problem with some PHP code in WordPress and I *think* the solution has to do with loops. I've had a look at http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop and http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action but it's way over my head and I've already wasted my entire Saturday on this.

So the thing is I have a widget on my website's homepage. It displays the titles to the next 5 events happening and links to them. What I wanted to do was to also display the date when the events (they are like blog posts) were last modified.

The problem is that my code keeps returning the wrong date. I modified my post today, the 13th of December and it keeps outputting the 11th of December. I don't know where it's getting that date from. I've tried using both *the_modified_date()* and *get_the_modified_date()* with the same results. I'm guessing the function doesn't know which post to pull the date from and it has something to do with loops.

So I've been messing with the widget's code. Here's a simplified version of what I have:

```
foreach ($events as $event) {

  if ( $event['event_date'] >= $site_date ) {

    $lastMod = get_the_modified_date($phpformatstring);
    echo $lastMod;

    echo '<br><a href="' . get_permalink($event['ID']) . '"  >' . get_the_title($event['ID']) . '</a>';

    if ( !empty( $widget_display_count ) ) {
      $counter++;
      if ( $counter == $widget_display_count )
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

I really hope someone can help me. If you want to try it with the widget I'm using, it's one called [Events Listing Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/events-listing-widget/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_the_modified_date()` needs the `$post` global. The plugin is iterating over the results of a wpdb query so technically there's no WP loop.

Something like `global $post; $post = get_post( $event['ID'] ); setup_postdata( $post );` right before the `get_the_modified_date()` call should work. Don't forget to reset the post data afterwards with `wp_reset_postdata();`

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_modified_date()` acts on the current post in the loop.

The function uses `get_post_modified_time()` to get the date which will accept a post ID.

Replace:

```
$lastMod = get_the_modified_date($phpformatstring);
```

With:

```
$lastMod = get_post_modified_time( $phpformatstring, null, $event['ID'], true );
```